# for loop - highscore array

Tags: c#, for-loop

So I'm trying to make this loop that goes through every index of highscore array(scorelist) to check if the current score(playerScore) is higher than the current index. If the if statement gets a "yes", then it should push all scores down(or is that higher?) along the index and put playerScore at where it should be.

```
{
    Console.Write("input name: ");
    string playerName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("input score: ");
    int playerScore = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (playerScore > scoreList[i])
        {
            int nextNo = 9;
            for (int n = 10; n > 0; n--)
            {

                scoreList[n] = scoreList[nextNo];
                nameList[n] = nameList[nextNo];
                nextNo--;
            }
            scoreList[i] = playerScore;
            nameList[i] = playerName;
        }
    }
}
```

With this current code, it just places playerScore on the first index(IF it is higher than what was previously stored there), then copies it along the rest of the index. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: If I'm getting it correctly, you wish to finish with a sort array from the lower score to the higher?

Comment: Try to add some breakpoints and check the values in the array while you are running the loop. You should figure out the problem fairly quickly.

Comment: Are you trying to sort by score.

Comment: As Roee suggested: use a List<scores> and then sort it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done much easier:

```
int prev = playerScore;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (playerScore > scoreList[i])
    {
        int temp = scoreList[i];
        scoreList[i] = prev;
        prev = temp;
    }
}
```

I assumed, that you only need top 10 results (and your array already has 10 elements in it).

Comment: Thanks. This was what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Change your array to a `List<int>` and use this code:

```
var scorelist = new List<int>();

//populate your scorelist;

var playerScore = someintValue;

var firstlower = scorelist.FirstOrDefault(x => x < playerScore);

if (firstlower != null)
    scorelist.Insert(playerScore, scoreList.IndexOf(firstlower);
else
    scorelist.add(playerScore);
```

**Edit:**

If you need to crop the list to 10 items max after inserting, just:

`scorelist = scorelist.Take(10).ToList();`

Comment: As a side comment, with the advent of [`LinQ`](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query), `for` loops are pretty much deprecated when it comes to finding stuff inside a `List` or `Array`.

Comment: Good, but how to limit the list to 10 scores?

Comment: @Steve, what exactly do you mean by that? do you want to crop the list after inserting the new item?

Comment: yes, now the answer is respecting the intrinsic limits posed by the OP

Comment: @HighCore: `List<T>.Find(Predicate match)` and `Array.Find(T array[], Predicate match)` have both been around since .Net 2, so one could argue that looping to find stuff in lists and arrays has been deprecated even longer than since Linq arrived!